# Correct approach to mongoose schema collection property

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to read a collection identified connected to a mongoose `model`. Is the correct approach to read the property `model.schema.options.collection` directly or is there any more suitable approach?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have understood, you want to use the property of your mongoose schema. i will provide you with a small example to how you can use it effectively.

**Your model file**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Schema for User
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
         type: String,
    },
    email: {
         type: String
    },
    password: {
         type: String,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

In your **function** where you want to include this **model**

```
var User = require('/path/models/user');

var  UserController = {
     create: function(req, res){

           var user = new User();

           user.name = req.body.name;
           user.email = req.body.email;
           user.password = req.body.password;

           //rest of the functionality on these bod params.
     }
}
```

I hope this small example will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, however, my question was about something else. I have a counter collection for other collection, according this recommendation https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Thanks, however, my question was about something else. I have a counter collection for other collection, according this recommendation https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ . I use the collection name as the _id, so for example, for collection 'products', I have a record in the counter collection { _id:'products', seq: (number)}, for collection 'questions', I have a record in the counter collection { _id:'questions', seq: (number)}.

Comment: So, my question was, if it is correct to get a collection name from Mongoose model by reading the property model.schema.options.collection, or if there is a better way, because reading the property model.schema.options.collection is just a hack, and it can change in later version then causing that it won't work.